# Por qué no obtiene mi archivo?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, local-storage, laravel-livewire

Buen día programadores, estoy batallando con algo uso laravel 7 y livewire, necesito acceder al directorio storage para recuperar una imagen. mi mensaje de error dice:

Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException
File not found at path: Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/aportes/storage/app/imagenes/20201009182340.png

el archivo se encuentra allí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi componente tengo esto:

```
$this->nom_imagen = Storage::get(storage_path().'/app/imagenes/'.$aporte->imagen);
```

y en la vista tengo esto:

Comment: No es necesario poner una ruta absoluta, `Storage::get()` usa la ruta relativa del archivo de configuración, por lo que deberías buscar la imagen así: `Storage::get('/imagenes/'.$aporte->imagen);`

Comment: pero viste mi error, está exactamente la ruta de mi archivo

Comment: Entonces el error persiste?

Comment: de hecho ahora me da otro error: InvalidArgumentException
Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Comment: Podrías poner lo que retorna `$aporte->imagen` por favor?

Comment: Una consulta has modificado el archivo `config/filesystems.php`

Comment: @FelipeUrcia Si, lo modifique intentando hacer lo que sugirieron otros. solo agregue esto: 'local_public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => public_path(),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
PD. no modifique lo que ya estaba.

Comment: otra cosa, intente crear un alias, pero no me funciono, si yo coloco mi imagen en el public/imagenes, lo obtengo sin problemas, el detalle es que lo guardo en un lado y lo puedo obtener de otro lado. y mi metodo de storage esta asi: $this->imagen->storeAs('imagenes',date('YmdHis').'.png'),

Comment: Has modificado, pero sigues usando el metodo `Storage::get()`, no deberias, déjame poner la respuesta, y ojala sirva.

Comment: si, es que lo modifique y lo intente usar y de ver que no me sirvio entonces segui usando el mismo metodo, intentando hacer que funcionara el metodo original

Comment: Hiciste `php artisan storage:link`? No deberías leer archivos directamente de tu carpeta storage, por eso se crean links a la carpeta public.

Comment: si hice eso php artisan storage:link, pero no pude hacer lo demas.

Comment: Verificaste que tengas iniciado apache y mysql en xampp?

Comment: Si, aunque uso laravel siempre activo mi apache porque estoy verificando mi phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas utilizar el metodo `Storage::get` deberias modificar el archivo `config/filesystems.php`, para esto debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        // 'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'root' => storage_path(),
    ],
]
```

De esta manera ya podrías usarlo de esta manera.

```
$this->nom_imagen = Storage::get('app/imagenes/'.$aporte->imagen);
```

De otra manera podrías intentarlo de la siguiente manera también.

```
$this->nom_imagen= file_get_contents(storage_path('app/imagenes/'.$aporte->imagen);
```

Comment: Siempre me da el problema de: InvalidArgumentException
Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Comment: Con cualquiera de las 2 ?, intenta colocar la captura de la imagen dentro de utf8_encode(aqui el que usaste);

Comment: Si, con los dos